# How to copy paste multi-line text input without arbitrarily adding `\n` in jupyter-notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to take an interactive multi-line user input from a jupyter-notebook cell as follows:

```py
contents = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        contents.append(line)
    else:
        break
        
input_text = "\n".join(contents)
```

Example input text:

```
This is a multi-line input.
It is good to put several lines after each other. 
The reason of this is a good indentation.
One can use both tabs and spaces.
```

But when I copy paste a multi-line input from somewhere instead of passing it line by line manually, it concatenates into a space separated string like below:

[image]

How do I establish copy pasting multi-line text input without arbitrarily adding `\n` after each line?

Comment: It's a jupyter-lab specific issue. If you run the same script in console, line breaks will be handled correctly in input. Sadly I was not able to find any solution for jupyter.

Comment: Yes, the issue seems jupyter-notebook specific. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

A dirty work-around is possible, if you are able to pre-process the user input by adding '\r\n' or some other predefined delimiter that could be split afterwards

```
This is a multi-line input.\r\n
It is good to put several lines after each other.\r\n
The reason of this is a good indentation.\r\n
One can use both tabs and spaces.
```

you could use decoding

```
print(input().encode().decode('unicode_escape'))
```

Resulting output:

```
This is a multi-line input.
It is good to put several lines after each other.
The reason of this is a good indentation.
One can use both tabs and spaces.
```